# Changing Order $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_{-y}^{y}\int_{0}^{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz\,dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Aim**.
My objective is to conduct a self-evaluation to ascertain my ability to effectuate modifications, rather than resorting to facile alterations of the commands to mitigate the difficulty of the problem.

**Question**.
Rewrite the following integral in $\,dx\,dy\,dz$ and $\,dx\,dz\,dy$.
$$\displaystyle\mathrm{I}=\int_0^1 \int_{-y}^{y}\int_{0}^{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz\,dx\,dy.$$ Note: the integral basically calculates the following volume:

[image]

**My endeavors**.
Initially, I endeavored to compute the given problem utilizing the order $\displaystyle\,dz\,dx\,dy \Longrightarrow \,dx\,dz\,dy \Longrightarrow \,dx\,dy\,dz$ and treating the non-dependent variable in the inner and outer integrals as a constant. This circumstance has resulted in an increase in both the length and complexity of the problem at hand. I endeavored to render the graphical representation and manipulate its arrangement, however, the presence of the variable $\displaystyle y=\left|x\right|$ posed a formidable challenge, ultimately impeding my ability to attain the desired outcome. Any assistance rendered would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: The identification of the intervals for $z$ and $y$ can be deemed as a relatively straightforward task, specifically denoted as $0\leq z \leq 1$ and $0\leq y \leq \sqrt[4]{1-z}$. However, I am currently lacking comprehension regarding the variable x's alteration mechanism. As per the assertion posited by Anne Bauval in the comments section, the designated bound for the aforementioned term is $|x|\le\min\left(y,\sqrt[4]{1-z-y^4}\right)$. However, I am currently encountering difficulties in the process of animating said term.

[image]

Comment: Why change the order? SImply calculate this integral as it is, from inside to outside. I.e. calculate $A(x,y):=\int_{0}^{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz,$ then $B(y):=\int_{-y}^yA(x,y)dx$ and finally $\int_0^1B(y)dy.$

Comment: Dear op ,  there are many functions dx dy imply dy dx is not true unless you swap the integral sign along with it.

Comment: There is neither "variable $y=|x|$", nor "formidable challenge". Simply integrate naturally, as detailed in the first comment.

Comment: i think op means x=|y| that's definitely a typo on the limit of the 2nd integral.

Comment: but that does not effect anything anyways

Comment: My goal was to test myself to see if I could change it, rather than making the problem easier by changing orders, sirs.

Comment: $$0\le z\le1,$$$$0\le y\le\sqrt[4]{1-z},$$$$|x|\le\min\left(y,\sqrt[4]{1-z-y^4}\right).$$

Comment: Regrettably, it appears that the Wolfram does not yield an identical outcome to that of the initial problem when the integral is expressed in the $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[4]{1-z}}\int_{-\min\left(y,\sqrt[4]{1-z-y^4}\right)}^{\min\left(y,\sqrt[4]{1-z-y^4}\right)} \,dx\,dy\,dz$ format. Might I kindly request that you expound upon the methodology employed in arriving at your aforementioned conclusion, and also provide guidance on the appropriate manner in which to articulate the integral form?

Comment: Please show your attempts first. Telling us that you suffered a lot does not help. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The only problem with your $\mathrm{I}$ is  that  $1-x^4-y^4$ may be $<0.$ What do you then mean by $\int_{0}^{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz$? Do you want $\int_{0\le z\le1-x^4-y^4} \,dz$ (i.e. $0$), or $-\int^0_{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz$? If you showed your attempts, it would  also have clarified that. Can you please edit your post rather than comment it? (including "My goal was to test myself to see if I could change it, rather than making the problem easier by changing orders")

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've updated the question. The attempts I wrote were as follows:  ``In[8]:= Integrate[1,{y,0,1},{x,-y,y},{z,0,1-x^4-y^4}]
Out[8]= 3/5`` and ``In[7]:= Integrate[1,{z,0,1},{y,0,(1-z)^(1/4)},{x,-Min[y,(1-y^4-z)^(1/4)],Min[y,(1-y^4-z)^(1/4)]}]
Out[7]= -((Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Gamma[1/4])/(3 Gamma[-(1/4)]))``. The integral basically calculates the following volume: ``RegionPlot3D[0<=y<=1&&-y<=x<=y&&0<=z<=1-x^4-y^4,{x,-1,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1}]``

Comment: When I asked for your "attempts" I did not mean your Wolfram (or whatever) queries but your mathematical efforts to solve your problem (those about which you only told us they were painful), and not in comment, rather in your post. But the end of your comment at least answers my question; you want "0<=z<=1-x^4-y^4", which corresponds to my "$|x|\le\min\left(y,\sqrt[4]{1-z-y^4}\right)$" and to your second query, whereas in the first one, $|x|$ is only bounded by $y$ and when it is $>\sqrt[4]{1-y^4},$ the integral $\int_{0}^{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz$ is interpreted as $-\int^{0}_{1-x^4-y^4} \,dz.$